# How do I fix my Git credentials so that I can push to my remote repo on Github?

Tags: git, github, keychain

I created a repo on github, set up the repo url locally, and tried to push for the first time `git push origin main`.

It asked my for a password, but I noticed that the prompt was using the username of my other github account.
I ran a few git commands to change my credentials so that I can successfully push and be authenticated.

Im still not able to authenticate, with a password, but i figure i get this git situation fixed first because I feel like i dug myself into a hole by firing desperation shots.

first i changed my username
`git config --global credential.username "MyUserName"`
`git config --global credentials.username "MyUserName"`

then I ran

`git config --global credential.helper manager`
then
`git config --global alias.credential-manager "credential-manager-core"`
and now I'm getting a message that says
`expansion of alias 'credential-manager' failed; 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`
when I try to push.

I also deleted my github info from Keychain on macOS.

Comment: Neither `user.name` nor `user.email` have anything at all to do with authentication. What does `git remote -v` say on that repo?

Comment: when I run `git remote -v` it gives me the correct repo on gitub that i'm trying to push to. At this point I'm trying to figure out why I can't be authenicated, even when I'm using the token I've generated through GitHub.

Comment: I was actually able to figure it out. instead of using the fine-grain PAT from github I just used the classic token. I then went into the the `.git-credentials` file and updated it with `https://<your_username>:<your_token>@github.com`. I then ran `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain` to tell Git to store and retrieve credentials from the macOS Keychain.
When I ran `git push origin main`, I was prompted for password, then I entered the new token. I had the Keychain open, and saw it update in realtime. So I'm good to go now!

Answer (score -3):

Your Git client username and email are both stored in the text file ".gitconfig" in your local user home directory.

On Windows this would be (for example) C:\Users\Bob\.gitconfig

Instead of running the above commands, you can just edit this file directly with your favorite text editor.

It should contain something like this (replace with your own data):

```
[user]
    email = example@example.com
    name = Bob
```

If you wish to push existing code to a new (empty) repository on GitHub, they describe in details how to do it.

Hopefully this will help you. :-)